# Ajax jquery gives 403 forbidden

Tags: jquery, apache

I'm using simple jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    data: "ajaxFile=getNews&limit",
    dataType: 'html',
})
```

And it works fine on my webserver (apache) but only when I have url like "example.com" but I have 403 forbidden when trying 'www.example.com'. 
Not sure why is that? the url for ajax_handler.pgp is relative, 
so should work on both www and non www urls?

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration issue rather than an issue with the Ajax call?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 the server refuses to allow the requested action.

Comment: IF you are browsing on the www. url of your site and make a request to the non-www. url it counts as a cross domain request. My guess is that requests are being forwarded on the server from non-www. to www.

Comment: Also I'm reluctant to answer this after seeing your profile, as you didn't accept the answer to your last question either (thanked the author for it instead).

Comment: SoonDead: just did it now

Comment: regards the cross domain request it is strange as im not giving the full url to the php file in ajax call, just 'ajax_handler.php'.

Comment: ok, so i guess when i use url like 'file.php' in ajax call it is always non-www url? no matter what is the browser current url

Comment: 'file.php' is a relative url, it will not be a cross-domain request, don't worry. It is more likely that apache can't access the php file. run a chown on the file in question and give it chmod 644 (or even chmod 600 is enough if the user running apache is you).

Comment: Use F12 / Network tab to ascertain exactly which URL is being used. Then you can stop assuming and start analysing. For a 403, usually it's going off  to a URL you don't expect

Comment: It just ocurred to me... this is javascript. Javascipt doesn't run on the web server it runs on the client. So Apache is irrelevant here. Unless you are using node.js or something else. Please clarify if you are.